Access pCloudDrive virtual drive from linux guest in windows 10 host os when using oracle VM Virtual Box
I have installed pcloud drive in lubuntu guest OS. My host OS is Windows 10. Now wanted to access pCloudDrive from my host os Windows 10. So what are the different options that i have, please suggest.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
